# Diff between Server Library and Class library in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

What is the difference between Server Library and Class library in Netbeans?

Comment: Knowing whether server libraries are excluded from the distributable package would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Server Library** refers to a Application or Web Application library, a library like servlet-api.jar in *Tomcat* or jboss.all.jar in *JBoss*.

while

a **ClassLibrary** refers to a library outside the standard Server Library scope, like a log4j.jar. A class library is also a valid .jar class archive written by someone like yourself.