# Difference between server library and registered library in NetBeans

Tags: maven, netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-12

When I do the following:

1. Right click project
2. Properties
3. On the opened window I click Frameworks > Add framework
4. I can select which framework I can add but **I don't understand what is the difference between "Server library" and "Registered libraries".**
   [image: Add framework image]

**So questions that are bugging me:**

1. What is the difference between "Server library" and "Registered libraries"
2. Can I add a new server library beside the ones that are in the drop select element, if yes how
3. Can I add a new registered library beside the ones that are in the drop select element, if yes how
4. Is the registered library the same as a class library? Because there is already question about that ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540510/diff-between-server-library-and-class-library-in-netbeans))

My current understanding is that a server library is a library that comes bundled with the application server I am using (I am using Wildfly). So based on that logic I should not be able to add new server libraries, but I might be wrong, so please correct me.

EDIT 1 : I have both Netbeans 8 and Netbeans 12 installed on the same computer and I have noticed that on the Netbeans 8 it is offering me JSF 2.2 under server library, but on the Netbeans 12 it is offerming me JSF 2.3 under server library. I am pointing to the same server folder for both of them, so shouldn't the versions also match?

EDIT 2: Comments asked me how I created the project. I created a Maven Web Application through a wizard (New Projet > Java with Maven > Web Application > Entered the project name > Wildfly Application Server and Java EE 8 WEB)

Comment: [1] It looks like you have a created a Maven Web Application through a wizard, right? If so, add a Maven tag to your question, because that is highly relevant. Regardless, you should update your question with full details on exactly how you created that project so that others can attempt to reproduce your issue. [2] Note that if you create an Ant Web Application in NetBeans there is a third radio option (not shown in your screen) shot labeled _"Create New Library"_, and also a **Libraries** property that does not exist for Maven projects since libraries are handled via **pom.xml**.